# Several flavors for an Android application (Eclipse ADT)

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-adt

There is an Android application developed under and built with Eclipse/ADT. Now I have to make it exist in two flavours: the Market version (with the Google libraries for purchase support) and the version for Customer N (without that Google Play stuff but with some custom features).

I cannot refactor it into a library because this will break the version control history. It is important not to break the version control and to make sure the bugs fixed in the common part are fixed in both flavors. It is important to keep the directory structure (*src/ res/ libs/*). I cannot just introduce a flag because the requirement is to leave no trace of custom features in the market binary.

If I wanted to remove the custom features manually, I would *(1)* remove some source files (both java and resources) *and (2)* comment out some lines in some other source files (again, both java and XML resources).

***How do I make the application exist in two versions (flavours) with slightly different feature sets?***

Comment: Use a login I think.

Answer (score 0):

So, nobody posted any answer.

I want the flavors to be:

1. Version-control-friendly (the requirement to always commit only one of configurations is ok)
2. simple in implementation (cheap in maintenance)
3. user-understandable
4. OS-independent

Let us consider a hypothetical project with two configurations: **master** and **slave**.

The idea is to introduce a markup that a simple script would be able to comment out or uncomment. It is better shown on images:

[image]
[image]

The latter two lines should be understood as "comment out on the master configuration". Well, in practice I'd recommend something like

```
/*master{*/
    if(something) {
        ...
    }
/*}master*/
```

but it is nice to know that you can put everything on a single line. Both `/*}*/` and `/*}configName*/` will work.

There is no "else": it would be completely wrong to specify something for configurations that you do not know.

The same trick works for XML resources:

[image]

*setconfig.py:*

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

import argparse
import os
import re

#set to False for debugging
really = True
verbose = True

# In the file 'fname',
# find the text matching "before oldtext after" (all occurrences) and
# replace 'oldtext' with 'newtext' (all occurrences).
# If 'mandatory' is true, raise an exception if no replacements were made.
def fileReplace(fname,before,newtext,after,oldtextpattern=r"[\w.]+",mandatory=True):
    with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
        read_data = f.read()
        pattern = r"("+re.escape(before)+r")"+oldtextpattern+"("+re.escape(after)+r")"
        replacement = r"\g<1>"+newtext+r"\g<2>"
        new_data,replacements_made = re.subn(pattern,replacement,read_data,flags=re.MULTILINE)
        if replacements_made and really:
            if new_data!=read_data:
                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate()
                f.write(new_data)
            if verbose:
                print "patching ",fname," (",replacements_made," occurrence" + ("s" if 1!=replacements_made else ""),")",newtext,("-- no changes" if new_data==read_data else "-- ***CHANGED***")
        elif replacements_made:
            print "\n\n\n\n"
            print fname,":"
            print new_data
        elif mandatory:
            raise Exception("cannot patch the file: "+fname+" with ["+newtext+"] instead of '"+before+"{"+oldtextpattern+"}"+after+"'")

def enableConfigInFile(flavour,fname, enable=True):
    if enable:
        symbol=r"*"
        oldsymbol=re.escape("/")
    else:
        symbol=r"/"
        oldsymbol=re.escape("*")
    fileReplace(fname, "/*"+flavour+"{",symbol,"/",oldtextpattern=oldsymbol, mandatory=False)

def enableConfigInXmlFile(flavour,fname, enable=True):
    if enable:
        startsymbol=r"<!--"
        endsymbol=r"-->"
        oldstartsymbol=re.escape("X!==")
        oldendsymbol=re.escape("==X")
    else:
        startsymbol=r"X!=="
        endsymbol=r"==X"
        oldstartsymbol=re.escape("<!--")
        oldendsymbol=re.escape("-->")
    fileReplace(fname, "<!--"+flavour+"{", endsymbol, "", oldtextpattern=oldendsymbol, mandatory=False)
    fileReplace(fname, "", startsymbol, "}"+flavour+"-->", oldtextpattern=oldstartsymbol, mandatory=False)

def enableConfig(flavour, enable=True):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=True):
        # ignore version control directories
        # Why .hg- and .git- ? Sometimes we need to hide .hg or .git from programs like `meld`.
        # (`meld` ignores .hg if it finds .git)
        if '.svn' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.svn')
        if '.svn-' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.svn-')
        if '.hg' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.hg')
        if '.hg-' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.hg-')
        if '.git' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.git')
        if '.git-' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.git-')

        for name in files:
            if name.endswith('.java'):
                enableConfigInFile(flavour, os.path.join(root, name), enable)
            elif name.endswith('.xml'):
                enableConfigInXmlFile(flavour, os.path.join(root, name), enable)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--master', dest='conf', action='store_const', const='master', help='configure as the master')
    parser.add_argument('--slave', dest='conf', action='store_const', const='slave', help='configure as a slave')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.conf is None:
        parser.print_help()
    else:
        print "setting configuration: "+args.conf

    # this is where you can implement a hierarchy of configurations: e.g. super-master would enable both `master` and `super-master`

    if args.conf == "master":
        enableConfig("slave", enable=False)
        enableConfig("master")
    elif args.conf == "slave":
        enableConfig("master", enable=False)
        enableConfig("slave")
    # how to extend this to a hierarchy of configurations:
    # let the child configuration call enableConfig() first for the parent and then for itself
#    elif args.conf == "supermaster":
#        enableConfig("slave", enable=False)
#        enableConfig("master")
#        enableConfig("supermaster")
```

Used as:

```
./setconfig.py --slave
```

or

```
./setconfig.py --master
```

Downside: the `/**  docs */` comments interfere with the `/*master{*/`...`/*}master*/` structure.

Just in case, I use Python 2.7.3.

You are welcome to rewrite the above script in any other language (like perl or bash) and publish the code.

Answer (score 0):

Another version of the same script. It is better suited for a large number of configurations. It supports ancestor configurations. You cannot set configurations *linux* and *master* separately: you must define *linux-master*. This happens because it disables or enables each configuration is knows, no configuration is left untouched. OTOH, you can have two copies of this script, e.g. one for selecting the OS and another for selecting the user access level.

*setConfig.1.py:*

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# coding: utf-8

# the configuration list format is: one configuration on each line, first configuration name then names of parent configurations, e.g.:
# guest
# basic
# advanced basic
# superuser advanced
# linux
# windows
# customer1 superuser linux
# customer2 basic windows
# customer3 guest windows

CONFIGURATIONS = """
 guest
 basic
 advanced basic
 superuser advanced
 linux
 windows
 customer1 superuser linux
 customer2 basic windows
 customer3 guest windows
"""

import argparse
import os
import re

#set to False for debugging
really = True
verbose = True

configList = filter(None,map(lambda l:l.split(), CONFIGURATIONS.split('\n')))
configParents = { l[0] : l for l in configList }
ancestorSets = {}
def findAncestors(name,visited,tovisit):
    visited.add(name)
    for a in tovisit:
        if not a in visited:
            visited.update(findAncestors(a,visited,configParents[a]))
    return visited
for c,p in configParents.iteritems():
    ancestorSets[c] = findAncestors(c,set(),p)

# In the file 'fname',
# find the text matching "before oldtext after" (all occurrences) and
# replace 'oldtext' with 'newtext' (all occurrences).
# If 'mandatory' is true, raise an exception if no replacements were made.
def fileReplace(fname,before,newtext,after,oldtextpattern=r"[\w.]+",mandatory=True):
    with open(fname, 'r+') as f:
        read_data = f.read()
        pattern = r"("+re.escape(before)+r")"+oldtextpattern+"("+re.escape(after)+r")"
        replacement = r"\g<1>"+newtext+r"\g<2>"
        new_data,replacements_made = re.subn(pattern,replacement,read_data,flags=re.MULTILINE)
        if replacements_made and really:
            if new_data!=read_data:
                f.seek(0)
                f.truncate()
                f.write(new_data)
            if verbose:
                print "patching ",fname," (",replacements_made," occurrence" + ("s" if 1!=replacements_made else ""),")",newtext,("-- no changes" if new_data==read_data else "-- ***CHANGED***")
        elif replacements_made:
            print "\n\n\n\n"
            print fname,":"
            print new_data
        elif mandatory:
            raise Exception("cannot patch the file: "+fname+" with ["+newtext+"] instead of '"+before+"{"+oldtextpattern+"}"+after+"'")

def enableConfigInFile(flavour,fname, enable=True):
    if enable:
        symbol=r"*"
        oldsymbol=re.escape("/")
    else:
        symbol=r"/"
        oldsymbol=re.escape("*")
    fileReplace(fname, "/*"+flavour+"{",symbol,"/",oldtextpattern=oldsymbol, mandatory=False)

def enableConfigInXmlFile(flavour,fname, enable=True):
    if enable:
        startsymbol=r"<!--"
        endsymbol=r"-->"
        oldstartsymbol=re.escape("X!==")
        oldendsymbol=re.escape("==X")
    else:
        startsymbol=r"X!=="
        endsymbol=r"==X"
        oldstartsymbol=re.escape("<!--")
        oldendsymbol=re.escape("-->")
    fileReplace(fname, "<!--"+flavour+"{", endsymbol, "", oldtextpattern=oldendsymbol, mandatory=False)
    fileReplace(fname, "", startsymbol, "}"+flavour+"-->", oldtextpattern=oldstartsymbol, mandatory=False)

def enableConfig(flavour, enable=True):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(".", topdown=True):
        # ignore version control directories
        # Why .hg- and .git- ? Sometimes we need to hide .hg or .git from programs like `meld`.
        # (`meld` ignores .hg if it finds .git)
        if '.svn' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.svn')
        if '.svn-' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.svn-')
        if '.hg' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.hg')
        if '.hg-' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.hg-')
        if '.git' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.git')
        if '.git-' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.git-')

        for name in files:
            if name.endswith('.java'):
                enableConfigInFile(flavour, os.path.join(root, name), enable)
            elif name.endswith('.xml'):
                enableConfigInXmlFile(flavour, os.path.join(root, name), enable)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    for c in configList:
        thisconf = c[0]
        parser.add_argument('--'+thisconf, dest='conf', action='store_const', const=thisconf, help='configure as: '+thisconf)

    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.conf is None:
        parser.print_help()
    else:
        print "setting configuration: "+args.conf

    toenable = ancestorSets[args.conf]
    for c in ancestorSets:
        print ("enabling " if c in toenable else "disabling ")+c
        enableConfig(c, enable=c in toenable)
```